# jekyll 2.2.0 | Error: Address already in use - bind(2)

Tags: jekyll

I am new to Jekyll blogging and trying to view blog locally on

```
http://localhost:4000
```

but failed.

```
➜ my-awesome-site > jekyll serve
Notice: for 10x faster LSI support, please install http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/
Configuration file: /home/Git/my-awesome-site/_config.yml
        Source: /home/Git/my-awesome-site
   Destination: /home/Git/my-awesome-site/_site
  Generating...
                done.
Configuration file: /home/Git/my-awesome-site/_config.yml
jekyll 2.2.0 | Error:  Address already in use - bind(2)
```

I tried

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000
$ lsof -wni tcp:4000
```

but both of them return nothing.

My Ruby version is:

```
➜ my-awesome-site > ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

What should I do next? I've re-installed jekyll already but the same problem remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to see which process is using that port, kill it and run again or try running jekyll on different port.

Comment: Could you please indicate how to run jekyll on a different port?

Comment: @controlled in your `_config.yml`, add `port: 4444` for example. Alternatively, you can do `jekyll serve --watch --port 4444`

Comment: Trying a different port helped me, as @TuanAnhTran said

Answer (score 28):

See the comments in http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/, should help you:

> If you need to kill the server, you can `kill -9 1234` where "1234" is
>   the PID.
>
> If you cannot find the PID, then do, `ps aux | grep jekyll`
>   and kill the instance. [Read more](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/shell/jobz5.html).

Comment: ➜ my-awesome-site > ps aux | grep jekyll
username         53521   0.0  0.0  2432784    612 s000  S+    2:12PM   0:00.00 grep jekyll

Comment: it seems that there is nothing to kill. The only running job that has keyword jekyll is "grep jekyll"

Answer (score 14):

Steps [here](http://www.noxidsoft.com/development/jekyll-tcpserver-error-address-already-in-use-bind-2/) fixed it for me. I had to append 'sudo' along with the commands.

```
$> sudo lsof -wni tcp:4000
```

It will give you information of process running on tcp port 4000 which also contains PID (Process ID). Now use command below to kill the process.

```
$> sudo kill -9 PID
```

Now you can execute `jekyll serve` command to start your site

Answer (score 3):

If [@Matifou's answer here doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25293131/4561887), do the following instead:

### The fix for anyone: run `jekyll serve` on an unused port:

Two ways:

1. In your `_config.yml` file, specify a port other than `4000` like this, for example:

   ```
   port: 4001
   ```
2. OR (my preferred choice), add `--port 4001` to your `jekyll serve` command, like this, for example:

   ```
   bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --port 4001
   ```

From: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#serve-command-options

See my answer here: [Is it possible to serve multiple Jekyll sites locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650749/is-it-possible-to-serve-multiple-jekyll-sites-locally/65512372#65512372)

### My particular problem: NoMachine is interfering:

When I run:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --drafts --unpublished
```

I get these errors:

> ```
> jekyll 3.9.0 | Error:  Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:4000
> .
> .
> .
> /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/socket.rb:201:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 127.0.0.1:4000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
> ```

`ps aux | grep jekyll` doesn't show any processes running except this `grep` command itself. So, that doesn't help.

`sudo lsof -wni tcp:4000`, however, shows a running `nxd` nx daemon process:

> ```
> $ sudo lsof -wni tcp:4000
> COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
> nxd     914803   nx    3u  IPv4 7606783      0t0  TCP *:4000 (LISTEN)
> nxd     914803   nx    4u  IPv6 7599664      0t0  TCP *:4000 (LISTEN)
> ```

I discovered this is due to my [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com) remote login server.

If running NoMachine, click on the NoMachine icon in the top-right of your task bar. Ex: this is on Ubuntu 20.04:

[image]

Then click on "Show server status" --> Ports, and you'll see that NoMachine is running `nx` on Port 4000, which is interfering:

[image]

**So, use the fix above to serve jekyll on a different port, such as `4001` instead of `4000`.** I recommend leaving the NoMachine port settings as-is, on port `4000`, because [NoMachine says](https://www.nomachine.com/AR01L00770):

> - Automatic **updates** require that hosts with NoMachine client or server installed have access to the NoMachine update server on port `4000` and use the TCP protocol.

### See also:

1. [Is it possible to serve multiple Jekyll sites locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650749/is-it-possible-to-serve-multiple-jekyll-sites-locally/65512372)

   1. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512372/4561887)