# Is it possible to serve multiple Jekyll sites locally?

Tags: jekyll

Every time I serve a Jekyll site from the command line it is served on port 4000. Two sites can't be served on the same port.

Is it possible to serve multiple Jekyll sites locally?

Comment: The server in jekyll is no replacement for a dedicated server.

Comment: @user3791372, notice that the scope here is local.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible to serve multiple Jekyll sites locally by setting different port numbers for each site using the Local Server Port serve command option.

See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#serve-command-options.

Set a port number other than Jekyll's default port (4000) in the site's `_config.yml` file or when serving the site via the command line.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Per the documentation, put e.g. `port: 4001` in your `_config.yml` file.

Answer (score 41):

You can also start the server with an additional argument `--port 1234` or `--host hostname`. For example:

```
$ jekyll serve --port 4001 --host my_hostname_or_ip
```

You can view all the possible CLI flags from the official Jekyll documentation - https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#serve-command-options

Comment: Hey, `--port` works not in all areas fine. The filter `{% link %}` will ignore the port. So links to pages on dev-env will be broken. Any idea to handle that?

Answer (score 6):

For multiple Jekyll sites, I just run this

`bundle exec jekyll serve --port <your_port_number>`

e.g

`bundle exec jekyll serve --port 4001`

Answer (score 4):

#### Two ways:

1. In your `_config.yml` file, specify a port other than `4000` like this, for example:

   ```
   port: 4001
   ```
2. OR (my preferred choice), add `--port 4001` to your `jekyll serve` command, like this, for example:

   ```
   bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --port 4001
   ```

From: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#serve-command-options

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal, go to the Jekyll site directory and start the server

```
jekyll serve --port 4001
```

Go to another directory and start the second site

```
jekyll serve --port 4002
```

Answer (score 3):

If you run it on mac docker client, provide host IP `0.0.0.0` will save your time a ton.

```
jekyll serve --port 4001 --host 0.0.0.0
```

By default, `127.0.0.1` is used for localhost and its NIC cannot receive any traffic from your mac host, whereas `0.0.0.0` means to accept traffic on all NICs

Comment: Just let me know the reason if you down-vote. I'd like to learn!