# Rails: Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I am trying to deploy Rails app with the Puma web server. When trying to start Puma server with a config file `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb` I get an error that the address is already in use.

Does someone know how to fix this?

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
[23699] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[23699] * Version 2.11.3 (ruby 2.0.0-p353), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
[23699] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[23699] * Environment: development
[23699] * Process workers: 2
[23699] * Preloading application
Jdbc-MySQL is only for use with JRuby
[23699] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:210:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:210:in `new'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:210:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:96:in `block in parse'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:82:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:82:in `parse'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/runner.rb:119:in `load_and_bind'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cluster.rb:302:in `run'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:216:in `run'
    from /rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/puma-2.11.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: it's exactly what it says. someone is already using port 3000. use netstat to figure out who is on port 3000

Comment: When I try to kill it I get a error `kill -59780 PID`. Tells me `invalid signal specification`. I used `lsof -wni tcp:3000` to show what is using port 3000.

Comment: kill -9 59780 (so "kill -9 pid_id" in general)

Comment: You can consider [my answer in this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75231668/4575793), where I also point to [111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592376/address-already-in-use-bind2-for-127-0-0-1-port-3000-errnoeaddrinuse) [222](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177751/ruby-on-rails-address-already-in-use-bind2-for-0-0-0-0-port-3000-errno) [333](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151736/jekyll-2-2-0-error-address-already-in-use-bind2)

Answer (score 358, accepted):

You need to use `kill -9 59780` with `59780` replaced with found PID number (use `lsof -wni tcp:3000` to see which process used `3000` port and get the process PID).

Or you can just modify your puma config change the tcp port `tcp://127.0.0.1:3000` from `3000` to `9292` or other port that not been used.

Or you can start your rails app by using:

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b tcp://127.0.0.1:3001
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. I got same error with OP. and what I realized is I already do `rails s` at another terminal. So that is why I got that error. then I used diff port to start the server  `rails s -p 9090`

Answer (score 192):

To kill the puma process first run

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

to show what is using port 3000. Then use the PID that comes with the result to run the kill process.

For example after running        lsof -wni tcp:3000 you might get something like

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    3366 dummy    8u  IPv4  16901      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000 (LISTEN)
```

Now run the following to kill the process. (where 3366 is the PID)

```
kill -9 3366
```

Should resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks @sawo-cliff it  solved my problem I had a another application running on port 3000.

Comment: How this answer add more information than the accepted one year ago?

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo, not quite sure I follow your question, but from the little I can glean from it, my answer added how to know which process id is running so as to know what to kill.

Comment: Yes. I can see now that the original answer DID include the same info. But I didn't fully understand what I needed to do until I read this version.

Answer (score 47):

you can also try this trick:

```
ps aux | grep puma
```

sample output:

```
myname           77921   0.0  0.0  2433828   1972 s000  R+   11:17AM   0:00.00 grep puma
myname           67661   0.0  2.3  2680504 191204 s002  S+   11:00AM   0:18.38 puma 3.11.2 (tcp://localhost:3000) [my_proj]
```

then:

```
kill -9 67661
```

Comment: Use `kill -9 67661` if `kill 67661` doesn't actually kill the process for you (as per the example above). That worked for me! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Found the script below in this [github issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/516#issuecomment-270979956). Works great for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
port = ARGV.first || 3000
system("sudo echo kill-server-on #{port}")

pid = `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P | grep #{port} | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -n 1`.strip
puts "PID: #{pid}"
`kill -9 #{pid}` unless pid.empty?
```

You can either run it in irb or inside a ruby file.

For the latter, create `server_killer.rb` then run it with `ruby server_killer.rb`

Comment: This worked for me thank you, but I took out the sudo, as I did not seem to need it.

Answer (score 3):

SOLUTION FOR GENERAL Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

This issue is because we are trying to use the same port which is already is use. so we have to stop the services running on that port so that we can run another services.
we can use `kill` like `kill -9 {PID}`where {PID} is the PID of the services running on that port. To know the PID of any services lets say "firefox" we can use commands like `pidof firefox`, `ps aux | grep -i firefox` ,`pgrep firefox`  and then use the `kill` command to stop that service.

sometime we might get into the situation where we don't know the `PID` or the service name to search for in this case we can use the following little ruby code to do it for us.(in this case port 3000, you can change it according to your need)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
port = ARGV.first || 3000
system("sudo echo kill-server-on #{port}")

pid = `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P | grep #{port} | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -n 1`.strip
puts "PID: #{pid}"
`kill -9 #{pid}` unless pid.empty?
```

save it as something.rb and run `sudo ruby something.rb`

Answer (score 2):

If the above solutions don't work on ubuntu/linux then you can try this

```
sudo fuser -k -n tcp port
```

Run it several times to kill processes on your port of choosing. port could be 3000 for example. You would have killed all the processes if you see no output after running the command

Answer (score 1):

You can find and kill the running processes: `ps aux | grep puma`
Then you can kill it with `kill PID`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my Macbook Air, running Rails 5.0.3, Puma 5.2.2

Tried running
`lsof -wni tcp:3000`  but there's no process on this port number.

Managed to fix this by running:

`export PORT=3000` on my terminal, then I just added this extra line to my `.bash_profile`

Comment: I know this is an older post, but I'm currently in the process of updating an older Rails app and came across this answer after running into the problem from the original post. This worked, but I'm not really understanding why that's the case. Could you offer a further explanation of this? I'm going to keep digging in the meantime and update this comment as I find more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple open tmp/pids/server.pid and there you will find pid
e.g->42345
just type kill -9 42345

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a hung `ruby` process from a previous `rails`/`puma` instance, which I also answered in [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75231668/4575793). **TL;DR:** it was just **`killall ruby -9`**.

---

This is supposed to be an easier fix then [this more general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36131230/4575793). I could check if it applies first like this:

```bash
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000 # To know the process that blocks the port, returns:
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    10660 simon    8u  IPv4  67071      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
ruby    10672 simon    8u  IPv4  67071      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
ruby    10684 simon    8u  IPv4  67071      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be old but in my case, it was because of docker. Hope it will help others.