# rails nginx and puma error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I've just deployed a new app and got some errors. 
my config files looks like the ones in here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

puma log:

```
    === puma startup: 2016-06-11 13:10:07 +0200 ===
! Unable to load application: Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for [::]:2010
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/home/admrails/apps/Paris/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/puma)
```

nginx log:

```
    2016/06/11 13:16:37 [crit] 29360#0: *3 connect() to unix:///home/admrails/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/Paris-puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myIP, request: "GET /en/log_in HTTP/1.1", upstream: 

"http://unix:///home/admrails/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/myapp-puma.sock:/en/log_in", host: "localhost"
```

Any idea ?
Tkx

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039998/address-already-in-use-bind2-errnoeaddrinuse

Comment: There is no process using port 3000

Comment: Can you show how you're starting puma? The command?

Comment: I deploy with capistrano  using "cap production deploy" and then restart nginx (like this tuto https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma). Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by syntaxhighlighter !!