# .rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:328:in `listen': Address already in use - listen(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, puma

I've changed from Mac to Linux (Ubuntu) a couple of days ago and I cloned the repo from my team project in GitHub. (It was working before this with Mac). But now, I've got this problem.

I was trying to start the server on local Unix socket (3000) by running

```
bundle exec puma
```

but it shows me these errors instead.

```
[3217] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[3217] * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[3217] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 16
[3217] * Environment: development
[3217] * Process workers: 1
[3217] * Preloading application
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
        12: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        11: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
        10: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/puma:23:in `load'
         9: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
         8: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
         7: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
         6: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/cluster.rb:413:in `run'
         5: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/runner.rb:161:in `load_and_bind'
         4: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `parse'
         3: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:90:in `each'
         2: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:151:in `block in parse'
         1: from /home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:328:in `add_unix_listener'
/home/shaun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:328:in `listen': Address already in use - listen(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

I've then tried to run

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b tcp://127.0.0.1:3001
```

but the server stops right away without running it.

```
[3263] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[3263] * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
[3263] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 16
[3263] * Environment: development
[3263] * Process workers: 1
[3263] * Preloading application
[3263] * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3001
[3263] Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I've also tried the methods given in this post: [Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039998/address-already-in-use-bind2-errnoeaddrinuse)

Like

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

but nothing was shown for me to kill the Pid process.

Can someone please help?

These are the software versions I'm using:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
- Puma version 4.3.3

This is the code in config/puma.rb

```
# vars
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
environment ENV.fetch("RACK_ENV") { "production" }

# pidfile and state
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"

# Threads for serving requests
threads 1, 16

# Workers (cpu cores)
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 1 }
preload_app!

# Unix socket to for nginix reverse proxy
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

# Port for local server use
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Debugging
debug

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

activate_control_app

rackup "#{app_dir}/config.ru"
```

Comment: Have you restarted the computer and tried again? If so, how are you defining your listening options in `config/puma.rb`?

Comment: @anothermh yes i did restart my computer couple times these few days. Is this the line you're looking for? ```port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }```

Comment: ```app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

environment ENV.fetch("RACK_ENV") { "development" }

pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"

# Threads for serving requests
threads 1, 16

workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 1 }
preload_app!

bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
debug

stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

activate_control_app

rackup "#{app_dir}/config.ru"```

Comment: Don't post code in comments. That's an unreadable mess. Updates to your question go in your question.

Comment: @anothermh alright got it. thanks for letting me know. I've updated them in my question above. Really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running another program on port `3000`. Run `lsof -i:3000` and stop it using `kill` command when there are some result from the command.

Comment: Yes, I did. But nothing is coming out after running the code ```lsof -i:3000``` in the terminal.

Comment: What does come out when you run `sudo lsof -i:3000`?

Comment: just tried this as well. but there's no result at all

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/UNIXServer.html#method-i-listen
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/UNIXServer.html#method-i-listen-label-Windows+Exceptions
So, the error you see seems to occur only on Windows.

Comment: Yes i'm on windows. Just swap from Mac to a Windows laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's really helpful. :) But I'm still a little confused. Am I supposed to put the code in config/puma.rb to solve the problem?

Comment: OK, so you're on Windows, but your post says you're on Ubuntu (sorry I found it just now). Is it WSL? If so, maybe `lsof` command cannot find the program using port `3000` from Windows.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I've actually installed ubuntu on my Windows. Yup I'm using WSL in VS code. Is this why lsof not working? But still, thanks for helping anyway. :)

Comment: If you could provide your `config/puma.rb`, I might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Yeah sure. I'll update to my post. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks. So could you confirm that `"unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"` does exist?

Comment: Yes, it's in the shared/sockets/puma.sock but it's an empty file when I open it in VS Code. Am I supposed to add code into the file?

Comment: Unix socket file is such a file, it's empty and that's fine.

Comment: Could you try to delete `port` line and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah i did try comment out the port line but same error popping out :(