# Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost, puma, foreman

First of all, I know [this error has already been listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039998/address-already-in-use-bind2-errnoeaddrinuse), but the question was different.

I have a Rails 4 app, that I used to run on Puma.

Then, a friend of mines worked on the app, and recommended that we use Foreman instead.

So, I used to run the app locally with `rails s` in Terminal.

Now, I am supposed to do it with `foreman start`.

The problem is, almost every time I try to launch the app, I get the following error:

```
foreman start
08:42:28 web.1  | started with pid 3398
08:42:28 web.1  | [3398] Puma starting in cluster mode...
08:42:28 web.1  | [3398] * Version 2.13.4 (ruby 2.2.1-p85), codename: A Midsummer Code's Dream
08:42:28 web.1  | [3398] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
08:42:28 web.1  | [3398] * Environment: development
08:42:28 web.1  | [3398] * Process workers: 2
08:42:28 web.1  | [3398] * Preloading application
08:42:31 web.1  | [3398] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
08:42:31 web.1  | /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:231:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:231:in `new'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:231:in `add_tcp_listener'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:98:in `block in parse'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:84:in `each'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:84:in `parse'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/runner.rb:119:in `load_and_bind'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/cluster.rb:304:in `run'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/cli.rb:215:in `run'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/puma-2.13.4/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/puma:23:in `load'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
08:42:31 web.1  |   from /Users/TXC/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
08:42:31 web.1  | exited with code 1
08:42:31 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

How can I fix this?

—————

**UPDATE**: I also tried both things below, [as recommended here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/cant-start-the-rails-server):

```
ps aux | grep rails
3547   0,0  0,0  2434840    752 s000  S+    8:48     0:00.00 grep rails
```

But there is no `ruby bin/rails server`

and that:

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    808  TXC    8u  IPv4 0x4f6da234a6116dab      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
ruby    809  TXC    8u  IPv4 0x4f6da234a6116dab      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
ruby    810  TXC    8u  IPv4 0x4f6da234a6116dab      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

but I am not sure of what I am supposed to do with this.

Am I supposed to restart my computer every time I want to launch the app locally?

Comment: If you run `netstat -na` do you see something else using port 3000?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is pretty new to me, so please excuse my dumb question: where am I supposed to look at, exactly? The command generated like 200 lines of information.

Comment: based on your update using `lsof`, `ruby` is running but it's "headless" since you can't control it from the command line. you'll need to stop the process using port 3000 before you can start a new one. try `killall -9 ruby` and then start your app.

Comment: Thanks a gain for your comment. I ran `killall -9 ruby` and got the following error: `No matching processes belonging to you were found`

Comment: reboot it like it's Windows

Comment: Thanks @Zepplock, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: I won't add it as an acceptable answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Puma, run `ps aux | grep puma`

```
PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
4662   0.0  0.1  4601556   8820   ??  S    10:48am   1:10.37 puma: cluster worker 1: 4395 [my-app]
4661   0.0  0.1  4882676  10300   ??  S    10:48am   2:14.49 puma: cluster worker 0: 4395 [my-app]
4395   ??  S      0:16.88 puma 3.12.1 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [my-app]
```

Then kill those pids.

`kill -9 4395 4661 4662`

Comment: Or even quicker `pkill -9 -f puma`  (`-f` matches against the full entry rather than just the process name. might not be needed)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
After small investigation was found ntop

> `ntop` - display network usage in web browser

1. `netstat -tulpn`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

2. `nmap 127.0.0.1`

```
3000/tcp open  ppp
```

Answer (score 0):

[This code](https://github.com/pailoro/rails_server_killer) will automate the process of fixing it for you.

It is a ruby script to fix the problem "Address already in use" on a rails server

run it on terminal with:

```
ruby rails_server_killer.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was pretty easy. But please be aware that (as the command says) shuts down **ALL** instances of ruby. You could solve it more fine-grained than this, e.g. with [a strategy like you mentioned](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/cant-start-the-rails-server).

```
killall ruby
```

There is [a more general answer in this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36131230/4575793) which can be used to check if this easy fix applies first:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000 # To know the process that blocks the port, returns:
# COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
# ruby    10660 simon    8u  IPv4  67071      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
# ruby    10672 simon    8u  IPv4  67071      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
# ruby    10684 simon    8u  IPv4  67071      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

---

All other things didn't help me:

```
$ killall rails
# -> rails: no process found
$ killall puma
# -> puma: no process found
```

You can also consider these possibly related Q/A:

- [Ruby on Rails - Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177751/ruby-on-rails-address-already-in-use-bind2-for-0-0-0-0-port-3000-errno)
- [Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592376/address-already-in-use-bind2-for-127-0-0-1-port-3000-errnoeaddrinuse)
- [jekyll 2.2.0 | Error: Address already in use - bind(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151736/jekyll-2-2-0-error-address-already-in-use-bind2)