# Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I've tried `lsof -wni tcp:3000`
But ouput is empty.

The uput of `ps aux | grep puma`
is

```
kirillo+  139882  0.0  0.0  20504  2916 pts/1    S+   13:43   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS
```

But when I submit `kill -9 139882`

the output is:

```
kill 139882 failed: no such process
```

What should I do to start server on localhost:3000?

Comment: try this ```sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)```

Answer (score 1):

Docker container was using port 3000 :)