# Ruby on Rails - Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, port, puma

When I attempt to start my rails server from my local machine, I get the following error message.

```
/Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:269:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:269:in `new'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:269:in `add_tcp_listener'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:105:in `block in parse'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:144:in `load_and_bind'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:391:in `run'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:174:in `run'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.9.1/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:104:in `start'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zachdobbs/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /Users/zachdobbs/sample_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/zachdobbs/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/zachdobbs/sample_app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

This error occurred suddenly and I'm not sure what the cause of it could be. When I looked online I noticed that the issue could be another service running on the port 3000, but when I try and run 'lsof -i tcp:3000' I get no results.

Within puma.rb, I define.

```
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
```

When I change the port value to something such as 8080 the server will run. I am confused as to why the server will not launch on port 3000. Every command I have attempted to run has shown me no services running on that port.

Comment: Are you trying to run `lsof -i tcp:3000` as root? If not, you should do it with `sudo`. Cause it might be that process is running as other user. Try `sudo lsof -i :3000 | grep LISTEN`.

Comment: @MaksimKalmykov running as sudo still does not give me any results.

Comment: what does it return when you run `localhost:3000` on your browser ?

Comment: @sa77 'Safari Can't Connect to the Server'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
> sudo ps ax | grep rails
#1338 pts/1    Sl+    0:06 /usr/bin/ruby2.3 bin/rails c
#1707 pts/0    Rl+    0:07 /usr/bin/ruby2.3 bin/rails s

> sudo kill -9 1707

> rails s
```

Comment: Executing `sudo ps ax | grep rails` gives me one result: `1559 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep rails` and attempting to do `sudo kill -9 1559` results in `kill: 1559: No such process`

Comment: No you shouldn't kill the **grep rails**, you have to kill the process id that ends with `bin/rails s`. I have `rails c` mentioned as I'm running rails console as well

Comment: Ah, I see now. The problem still persists however that no server instances are being displayed and port 3000 appears to be unused, so I am still confused as to why the server is failing to launch

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a really old post but I had to answer just in case others get here as I did.

When you declare `port` or `bind` commands in the puma config it will try to bind to **all** those ports or addresses.

In this case you've specified `port` twice so it's trying to bind to both and the second one will fail.

Comment: This is correct. When using puma, it use default port 3000. It will throw this error when we specific same port.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was pretty easy. But please be aware that (as the command says) shuts down **ALL** instances of ruby. You could solve it more fine-grained than this, e.g. with [a strategy like Abhi mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46178976/4575793).

```
killall ruby
```

All other things didn't help me:

```
killall rails
# -> rails: no process found
killall puma
# -> puma: no process found
```

You can also consider these possibly related Q/A:

- [Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35182860/4575793)
- [Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592376/address-already-in-use-bind2-for-127-0-0-1-port-3000-errnoeaddrinuse)
- [jekyll 2.2.0 | Error: Address already in use - bind(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151736/jekyll-2-2-0-error-address-already-in-use-bind2)